# jhbuild sanitycheck not moving

Tags: 12.04, pygtk, jhbuild

I am following [Jhbuild](http://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/getting-started.html.en) documentation.

while doing `jhbuild sanitycheck` I am getting following problem.

```
root@august:/home/frank/jhbuild# jhbuild sanitycheck
You should not run jhbuild as root.
root@august:/home/frank/jhbuild# exit
logout
frank@august:~/jhbuild$ jhbuild sanitycheck
jhbuild: working directory (/opt/gnome/_jhbuild) can not be created
frank@august:~/jhbuild$
```

How I am supposed to move now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your /opt/gnome directory is not writable by you. either `chmod 777 /opt/gnome/ -R` or better yet, configure jhbuild to run from your home directory.

If you followed those directions exactly jhbuild would be running as a normal user not as root.